# Optional Parameters, certain combination of them required

Tags: python, optional-parameters

I have a general question as well as a specific use case.

Optional parameters are easy enough: `def func(a, b, c=None): ...` and then anywhere c might be used in the body just write `if c:` first, or something along those lines. But what about when a certain combination of parameters is required? The general case is to consider any arbitrary situation of which exact parameters exist or not. For a function `def func(a, b, c=None, d=None, e=None, f=None): ...` this would include silly things like: provide c and d but not e and f, or provide e only, or provide at least 3 of c, d, e, and f. But my use case doesn't require such generality.

For `def func(a, b, c=None, d=None): ...`, I want EXACTLY ONE OF c and d to be provided.

Solutions I've thought of include:
- in the body, manually check how many of c and d are not None, and if it's not exactly 1, return an error saying exactly 1 needs to be specified
ex.

```
def func(a, b, c=None, d=None):
    how_many_provided = len([arg for arg in [c, d] if arg]) # count the non-None optional args
    if not how_many_provided == 1:
        return "Hey, provide exactly 1 of 'c' and 'd'"
    if c:
        # stuff to do if c is provided
    elif d:
        # stuff to do if d is provided
```

- change the function to be `def func(a, b, e, f): ...` where e represents either c or d and f indicates which one of those e represents.
ex.

```
def func(a, b, e, f):
    if f == 'c':
        # stuff to do if c is provided, with e as c
    if f == 'd':
        # stuff to do if d is provided, with e as d
```

These would work, but what is the standard/accepted/pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: How will the user calling the function know what combinations are acceptable?

Comment: I second @Mark's question. You should instead write a function definition that takes `a, b, cd=None` and test `cd` to see if it's a `c` or a `d`, then act accordingly.

Comment: FYI in your first example it would look nicer to say `sum(arg is not None for arg in [c,d])` but YMMV

Comment: Is this python 3? It could make the answer a bit nicer by using keyword only args.

Comment: The acceptable combinations would be documented (in my case in a doc string in the function, but for other situations could be in external docs). Isn't that always how a user knows the details about using a function, besides reading the function itself?

Answer (score 4):

I would say the easiest way for your user in your simple case is to refactor to separate functions. Each function does the different work as described and then a common one e.g. for your last case

```
def funcC(a, b, c):
        # stuff to do if c is provided, with e as c
    common_func(a,b,c, None)

def funcD(a, b, d):
    # stuff to do if d is provided, with e as d
    common_func(a,b,None, d)
```

The user then knows what parameters matter and only the valid possible combinations can be used, the user does not have to guess or have a chance to call them incorrectly. You as providing the function can provide whatever is needed for the parameter the caller does not supply.

There are longer explanations of these found by googling for "flag parameters" e.g. [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html) [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1240739/151019) these tend to mention Boolean arguments but this in effect the same thing a different code path depending on a parameter which has no other effect.

Another phrase to look for is "control coupling"

Comment: I always prefer writing one catch-all function so the user doesn't have to CARE which parameters matter. E.G. `def func(a, b, **kwargs): if 'c' in kwargs and 'd' in kwargs: throwException(); if 'c' in kwargs: _funcC(a,b,kwargs['c']) elif 'd' in kwargs: _funcD(a,b,kwargs['d'])`

Comment: @AdamSmith The issue is the caller has to care as he has to choose not to provide a parameter i.e. in the question "I want EXACTLY ONE OF c and d to be provided."

Comment: I suppose I can't imagine a use-case where OP would REQUIRE that no two `c` and `d` are called and it isn't obvious to the user that that's so. I.E. a class constructor who can either get its info from a tuple or a string, one of those should be obvious.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Unit testing becomes much more difficult when a function accepts a variety of arguments. You have to test every valid form of input, as well as every invalid *combination* of inputs. When you use separate functions, unit testing remains simple. When a code base becomes a bit complex, this can be a great advantage.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the keyword args dict:

```
def func(a, b, **kwargs):
  valid_args = len(kwargs) == 1 and ('c' in kwargs or 'd' in kwargs)

  if not valid_args:
      return "Hey, provide exactly 1 of 'c' and 'd'"
  if 'c' in kwargs:
      # stuff to do if c is provided
  elif 'd' in kwargs:
      # stuff to do if d is provided
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not work nicely with IDEs and introspection and so

Comment: I'd be tempted by something like: `valid_args = len({'c', 'd'}.insection(kwargs)) == 1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one, which will allow the arguments be specified, and differentiates between `c=None` and `c` not given, while still providing the argument names explicitly:

```
undefined = object()

def func(a, b, c=undefined, d=undefined):
    if (c is undefined) ^ (d is undefined):
        raise TypeError("Hey, provide exactly 1 of 'c' and 'd'")

    ...
```

On Python 3, keyword only arguments make it even nicer, making sure that the caller explicitly specifies `c` or `d`:

```
def func(a, b, *, c=undefined, d=undefined):
    if (c is undefined) ^ (d is undefined):
        raise TypeError("Hey, provide exactly 1 of 'c' and 'd'")
```