# Most pythonic way dealing with combinations of parameters for instantiating a class?

Tags: python, oop, code-cleanup

Let's say I have a class Foo:

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_a(b, c):
        if not b or not c:
            raise ValueError("Invalid params!")
        return b + c

    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, c=None):
        if not a:
            a = Foo.get_a(b, c)
        self.a = a
```

The user can use the class with either `a` or both `b` and `c`. If a is provided, `b` and `c` are ignored.

What is better: erroring when all three parameters are provided (making sure the programmer is conscious of which one is being used) or putting it into the docs that `b` and `c` will be ignored if a is provided?

On one hand, erroring is more explicit, which is pythonic (*Explicit is better than implicit*). On the other hand, accepting whatever works is more practical (*Although practicality beats purity*).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457819/optional-parameters-certain-combination-of-them-required

Comment: @matsjoyce: not really, not in the context of producing instances of a class.

Comment: While `FOO(b,c)` is easier to type than `Foo(Foo.get_a(b,c))`, it's not clear that it's superior to simply `Foo(b+c)`. I'm sure your real code is more complicated, but consider whether it is really `Foo`'s responsibility to provide a way to combine `b` and `c` into `a`.

Comment: To make the question more explicit, I changed the title to mention class.

Comment: @chepner - this is just an example. It's an operation on both b and c and not necessarily as simple just b + c.

Fair point - you need to consider if it belongs in Foo in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd give the class a separate `classmethod` factory instead:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def from_b_and_c(cls, b, c):
        return cls(b + c)
```

This is the real Explicit option; you either create `Foo(a)`, *or* you use `Foo.from_b_and_c(b, c)` to produce an instance with very different arguments. This immediately documents how the parameters are separate; either you create an instance from just `a`, *or* you create an instance from both `b` and `c` together.

This is a common pattern; if you have more than one way to produce an instance, provide additional factory methods in the form of class methods.

For example, you can produce a `datetime.date()` class with:

- The [standard year, month and day](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date), `date(2014, 10, 23)`
- from your [system date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today), `date.today()`
- from a [POSIX timestamp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp), `date.fromtimestamp(1414018800.0)`
- from an [ordinal (days since 0001-1-1)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal), `date.fromordinal(735529)`.